# Any reason to keep extremely rude users here?

Tags: discussion, users, rude-or-abusive

I'm aware of a user who has zero contributions, and uses profanity.

I've flagged the comments as Unfriendly or Unkind.

[image]

But the user is still with us. It is hard to understand.

Does Stack Overflow really need this kind of users?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Rude behavior is not acceptable, and such content should be flagged, as you have done. If you think there's a pattern of problematic behavior, you need to raise a custom flag and explain the issue. If all you've done is flag comments as UU, that's not going to have any effect other than to delete the comments.

Comment: I also saw and flagged the comment. Sorry about what you have to see. Anyway, because you're an >10k rep user, I think you can raise a custom flag. Not sure though.

Comment: @justANewbie You don't need to flag the *actual* post where you saw the behavior. You can flag any post by that user (or even a random post if they don't have any), and explain the issue. Provide as much evidence, along with links, as you can, and that's fine. So basically anyone with the flagging privilege can do this, not just 10k users.

Comment: @cigien I will see. Raised the custom flag. But maybe only numbers matter

Comment: That user was suspended, so I suppose you got what you wanted. :)

Comment: @E_net4thecurator Yes, but I do not believe in redemption (especially such extremely rude and insulting ones). I am sure that he will repeat it again and again.

Comment: @0___________ The system does not forget. Repeated offenses are met with aggravated suspensions until they stop or they are stopped permanently. But please let us know if this particular user ever goes on another rampage.

Comment: "Any reason to keep extremely rude users here?" - *For science*.

Comment: Just to clarify @E_net4thecurator's comment in case it was unclear: Please **don't** let *us* know if the user goes on another rampage. Only let the moderators know via a custom flag.

Comment: Oh. Right, please read my comment as an appeal to check the facts within reason on how often that happens, definitely not as a call to public witch hunting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no place at Stack Overflow for that *behavior*. However, the user is another story. Everyone has their bad days, or bad times in life; that tends to play out poorly during interpersonal communication.

Generally users will be given a few shots at redemption. A gentle prod, a stern warning, an I told you so suspension, a serious face suspension, and a 9999 days kthxbai ban (these obviously aren't hard and fast rules, every occurrence is taken on a case-by-case basis). Newer users tend to skip steps.

Sorry you were on the receiving end of something like that, the sad truth is that behavior happens quite frequently on the internet. You won't find much of it at Stack Overflow though, because moderators are pretty used to dealing with it here and have a lot of tools available to combat it.

Use a custom flag if you encounter something like this, flagging as "It's unfriendly or unkind" just doesn't tell the whole story sometimes.

Comment: Re *"these are obviously hard fast rules"*: Don't you mean *"these are obviously* ***not*** *hard fast rules"* (my emphasis)? Or perhaps *"these are, obviously,* ***not*** *hard fast rules"* (my emphasis)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Yes, indeed. Both of those :) Suspensions and their durations are judged on a case-by-case basis by the individual Moderator, or by a group decision if warranted.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), a user usually has 3 chances. The first would be a simple warning, the second would be account suspension and the last would be account expulsion. This means that your helpful "unfriendly or unkind" flags will not always suspend/expel the user's account. Of course, you can raise a custom moderator flag if you see a pattern.